# ZF2 - Session rememberMe + 2xajax = Session object destruction failed

Tags: php, ajax, session, zend-framework2

i've got the following problem:

I use ZF2 and if I click a link at the main-navigation the subnavigation and the content load via AJAX(two requests)

if I use 
   class AuthStorage extends Storage\Session {

```
public function __construct($namespace = null, $member = null, $manager = null) {
    parent::__construct($namespace, $member, $manager);

    $this->session->getManager()->rememberMe(3600);
   }
}
```

i got the following error:
Warning: session_regenerate_id(): Session object destruction failed in [...]\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Session\SessionManager.php on line 260

this warning-msg just appears just in one ajaxrequest. never in both at the same time. but it's not always in the same request....

and another weird thing: the exactly same script is working at my friends computer...

any ideas? :-(

Comment: Well, that's not ZF2 issue, but `php.ini` If it cannot destruct an object (which means cannot delete a session file on a server), it would make sense to `chmod()` session directory on your host.

Comment: i already chmod the xampp/tmp -folder (it's the one linked in the php.ini), and i already loggend in as admin. system: win7 ... on linux-systems there isn't this problem, but on windows-pc's ... any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Create your own session manager and pass it into the Container as second parameter.  Don't need to delete old session to extend current.  Set default delete old session to false.

```
<?php
namespace My\Session;

use Zend\Session\SessionManager;

class Manager extends SessionManager
{
public function regenerateId($deleteOldSession = false)
{
    session_regenerate_id((bool) $deleteOldSession);
    return $this;
}   
}
```